# Turn containing a relative subordinate clause and a passive voice main clause

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, subordonnées, passif

I wrote in a email :

> Les modifications que tu m'avais dites faire ont été faites.

Is it correct such a structure ? Does it sound peculiar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not sound correct, but I'm not sure what you mean. Instead:

> Les modifications que tu m'avais dit de faire ont été faites.

If **you were asked** to do modifications, and they were done.

> Les modifications que tu m'avais dit faire ont été faites.

If that person **told you they would do** the modifications, and they were done.

Answer (score 2):

Nope sorry !

If you question the agreement of past participle `dites` :

> Les modifications **que** tu m'avais **dites** […]

`que` is object to the verb `dites`, therefore it should agree with it (feminine plural).

But here :

> Les modifications **que** tu m'avais dit de **faire** […]

`que` is object to the verb `faire`, therefore `dit` shouldn't agree (it has its own object, which is `de faire`).

> Les modifications que tu m'as dit faire

The meaning is different as explained by Pierre. No agreement for the same reason as above. This phrasing doesn't sound very idiomatic to me (western France), maybe ‘Les modifications que tu dis avoir faites’ will be prefered.

Note that `dit de faire` ends up sounding like `dite faire` in speech, I can imagine this could cause some confusion in a non-native speaker  :)